# Docker on ubuntu: need to install docker-compose separately? could not create container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin
```

docker-compose not installed?

```
docker-compose up
```

command not found:

```
sudo docker compose up
```

It is creating container, never complete, more than 1000s, still creating. no error message.

```
  CTRL + C: could not stop it.
```

It took only 30 seconds on windows to create the container.

Comment: Try to install docker-compose directly. You don't need to install docker-compose-plugin, just run sudo apt install docker-compose

Comment: sudo apt  install docker-compose  # version 1.25.0-1. After installation, it could not understand --profile option.

Comment: The docker-compose on windows is 1.27.0. How to upgrade it on Ubuntu?